# How can I easily (in java) generate file names from a mask string?

Tags: java, filenames

I want to generate file names from a mask in Java.

Something like 'Data-12-08-29-xxx.xml' from a mask like 'Data-${YY}-${MM}-${DD}-${var1}.xml'. I dont want to generate random file names, instead the file names would built according to a pattern provided at runtime.

I can imagine just what I need to create a nice, generic class that will handle this for all manner of cases, but I dont want to reinvent the wheel, if something exists out there that I can re-purpose and perhaps extend.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check log4j implementation. They have already solved the problem of accepting the file pattern.

Comment: @sundar that is not a solution, I am actually using it

Comment: How is this any different than exposing some data to a format or template string and evaluating it?

Comment: A solution can be built by parsing the string into tokens, building a format string, then replacing token values and re-assembling the string. But, I imagine it has been done already several times. I liked the log4j implementation suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small library called [AlephFormatter](https://github.com/nomemory/aleph-formatter) that allows you to have "named" parameters.

For example:

```
String result = template("#{errNo} -> #{c.simpleName} -> #{c.package.name}")
                .arg("errNo", 101)
                .arg("c", String.class)
                .fmt();


System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
Error number: 101 -> String -> java.lang
```

Answer (score 4):

the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class (the functionality behind `String.format()`) has a very powerful formatting syntax (much more powerful than MessageFormat).  It can handle variable substitution as well as date formatting.

Comment: Time saving suggestion. Thank you! I will hold out for a few more good ideas.

Comment: +1 I don't see anything here that can't be handled with a simple call to String.format()

Answer (score 2):

```
 Format f=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH.mm.ss");
 String fileName="Data-"+f.format(new Date() /*or a Date object which you saved previously*/).toString()+".xml";
```

This will give you something like Data-12-12-2012-14.55.32.xml

Comment: that only handles date formatting, not arbitrary variables (e.g. `var1` in the OP's example).

Comment: it's easy to add whatever you want String fileName="Data-"+f.format(new Date() ).toString()+SOME_VAR+".xml"; where SOME_VAR can be int, string or whatever else can be concatenated in a String

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat("Data-{0,number,#}-{1}-{2}-{3,number,#}.xml");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int variable = 555;
Integer[] args = {cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), variable};
String result = messageFormat.format(args);
System.out.println(result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Data-2012-8-29-555.xml

Answer (score 0):

The problem with String.format() is that you will be forced to use indices of your variables in the format string and a pattern similar to `%1$ty-%1$tm-%1$td-%2$03d` may be problematic for the user to deal with:

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
int number = 7;
String msg = String.format("Data-%1$ty-%1$tm-%1$td-%2$03d.xml", time, number);
```

In one of my projects I decided to use Apache Velocity (an example is given here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html). It is quite powerful tool for this kind of task but it gives a possibility of using meaningful variable names in your format `Date-${year}-${month}-${day}-${number}.xml`. First, you would have to add appropriate variables to the velocity context:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("number", "007");
context.put("year", ...);
```

but then, it will be much easier for the user to specify the format string..